# Developing Eclipse Plugin for displaying Web Content

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to write an Eclipse Plugin for displaying web content in Eclipse.
Kindly suggest some pointers as how to display web contents to user by writing
some Plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Browser](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/Browser.html) class to display web content.

You can find an example of Browser usage on the [JFaceSnippets page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JFaceSnippets#Snippet037FancyCustomTooltips).